# System.IO.IOException while trying to write text to file

Tags: vb.net, file-io

I need to be able to write to the text files after creating them

```
    'Check for file
    File.Open("AI\Log.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite)
    File.Open("AI\AI.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite)
    'Write to log
    If File.ReadAllText("AI\Log.txt") = "" Then
        File.AppendAllText("AI\Log.txt", "User>" + Input.Text)
        File.AppendAllText("AI\Log.txt", vbNewLine + "Console>" + Output.Lines.Last)
    Else
        File.AppendAllText("AI\Log.txt", vbNewLine + "User>" + Input.Text)
        File.AppendAllText("AI\Log.txt", vbNewLine + "Console>" + Output.Lines.Last)
    End If
```

Comment: What line is throwing the error? What does your stack trace say?

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the `System.IO` API correctly.

I see your code first opens the files using `File.Open` but then doesn't do anything with the returned stream object, the files thus remain opened, then you use the static `AppendAllText` method while you still have open handles (which you'll leak).

If you're just using `AppendAllText` then you don't need to use the static `File.ReadAllText` or `File.Open` methods at all.